# What is the purpose of period (.) in the ~/.bashrc

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've been studying the bash scripting then i noticed using the period wildcard in the bash script, in my sense the period treated as current directory,

I have snippet

```
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
```

**. /etc/bash_completion** In this script what is the use of the (.), period.

Comment: Did you try ```help source```?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/114300/whats-the-meaning-of-a-dot-before-a-command-in-shell

Answer (score 2):

`.` is used to `source` a file:

```
. /etc/bash_completion
```

is the same as

```
source /etc/bash_completion
```

Comment: Questions that are already answered elsewhere in the knowledgebase should be closed as duplicate so the already vetted/edited/voted-on answers can be used; answering them spreads out the moderation work (meaning folks need to vote on / edit / correct more copies of what should be the same answers).